# As Part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) Integration With Azure Pipeline and how to add Chrome Driver Config in Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, azure-devops, cicd

Pushed the JMeter Selenium Scripts into Azure GIT Repository, created the pipeline and run the pipeline.

Agents added are: JMeter, Command Line, Publish pipeline artifact and publish and download artifacts from Release pipelines.
[image]
In the scripts the JSR223 Sampler, counters and Chrome Driver Config are added and after execution of test html file also generated but observed Thread Group is not starting..
[image]
Also have dependencies like csv files path so How can I set the csv files path please?
[image]

In the **jmeter.logs got errors as  C:\LocalShare\Bhaskar\chromedriver_win32(2)\chromedriver.exe and csv path not found**

Due to this javaILLEGAL Exception errors occur.

Could anyone please help me how can I **add Chrome Driver Config, set Chrome Driver Config path and csv files path** In Azure Pipeline please?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory: on your Azure runner machine there is no `chromedriver.exe` under `C:\LocalShare\Bhaskar\chromedriver_win32(2)` folder.

If you're absolutely sure that the Azure machine which executes the pipeline is running Windows you can commit the `chromedriver.exe` along with your .jmx test script. Alternatively you can download and unpack the chromedriver using i.e. [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlet

In case of Linux you will need to download chromedriver for Linux.

And don't forget that [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-projects/) must also be installed on the Azure runner

---

Alternatively you can consider switching to [TaurusInstaller and TaurusRunner](https://github.com/algattik/azure-pipelines-jmeter-extension/blob/master/overview.md#about-the-jmeter-extension) pipes, [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) will download the necessary version of chromedriver automatically.

[Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/complete-taurus-course) is an automation-friendly framework which supports running JMeter tests (as well as Gatling, Selenium, Locust and many more) and makes some routine tasks faster and easier.